# Not able to see logs on Kibana

Tags: elastic-stack, elk

I created an elk folder in my local machine which contains a docker-compose.yml file, logstash config file, and log file to read the logs from.
I made the necessary changes in a spring boot app application.yaml file to log all the logs in my log file in the elk folder.
I executed the docker-compose file, which created three containers for elastic search, logstash and kibana.
I can get a success message on logstash logs, which means logstash is working correctly.
I can open the kibana console and create an index pattern.
**I am not able to see the logs getting reflected in kibana discover.**
**Followed all the steps on a Virtual Machine but faced the same issue.**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.16.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - elastic_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
    environment:
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx256m -Xms256m
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    image: logstash:7.16.2
    container_name: logstash
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /elk/logstash/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline
    command: logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - '9600:9600'
    environment:
 networks:
      - elk

  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.16.2
    container_name: kibana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5601:5601'
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - elk

volumes:
  elastic_data: {}

networks:
  elk:
```

```
input{
        file {
                path => "/temp/inlog.log"
        }
}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
        }
}
```

[Output on Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok6fO.png)